# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg()

Tags: php-7.3, ereg

I am using php v7.3.2 on Centos 7.6.
Before upgrading php the version was 5.4.
In v 5.4 i had no errors.
But in v 7.3.2 i got this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg() in
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.inc:1307 Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.inc(1284):
>   xmlrpcmsg->parseResponse('HTTP/1.0 200 OK...') #1
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.inc(931):
>   xmlrpcmsg->parseResponseFile(Resource id #21) #2
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.inc(872):
>   xmlrpc_client->sendPayloadHTTP10(Object(xmlrpcmsg), '127.0.0.1',
>   '1235', 240, '', '') #3
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/IBSng/inc/xmlrpc.php(43):
>   xmlrpc_client->send(Object(xmlrpcmsg), 240) #4
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/IBSng/inc/xmlrpc.php(27):
>   IBSxmlrpc->__sendXmlRpcRequest(Object(xmlrpcmsg), 240) #5
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/IBSng/inc/request.php(60):
>   IBSxmlrpc->sendRequest('login.login', Array) #6
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/IBSng/inc/auth.php(144): Request->send() #7
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/IBSng/inc/auth.php(111):
>   Auth->__sendAuthRequest() #8
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/IBSng/inc/auth.php(94):
>   Auth->__authenticateUser() #9 /usr/local/IBSng/ in
>   /usr/local/IBSng/interface/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.inc on line 1307

What is that error mean & how can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `preg_match()` instead of `ereg()` function.