# function ereg deprecated, how to update to preg_match?:

Tags: preg-match, ereg

I'm using an old php script that runs on php 5.2 but host no longer provides php below 5.4
I'm getting an error regarding function ereg that needs to be updated to preg_match but I have no idea how this is done and a look around the web isn't too helpful. Any help available?

Existing code:

```
if (!ereg('^/[^./][^/]/*$', $cfg["theme"]))
```

Comment: Maybe `if (!preg_match('~^/[^./][^/]/*$~', $cfg["theme"]))`?

Comment: Well blow me down with a feather, and bless your cotton socks! I've been trying to work this out for hours and I get an answer within minutes on SO. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
 if (!preg_match('~^/[^./][^/]/*$~', $cfg["theme"]))
```

Pay attention to the regex delimiter, here, `~`.